# Drawing on top of an image WFA

Tags: c#, winforms, image, draw

Im using WFA and C#, and im trying to draw an elipse on top of a picturebox containing an image. here is my code but currently its drawing behind of the PB.

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pb=new PictureBox();
    pb.Location=new Point(10,25);
    pb.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("fire2_clipped_rev_1.png");
    pb.Size = Image.FromFile("fire2_clipped_rev_1.png").Size;
    Truck.TruckF(pb.Location, pb.CreateGraphics());
    pb.Invalidate();
    Controls.Add(pb);
}

static Image truckf = Image.FromFile("fire2_clipped_rev_1.png");

public static void TruckF(Point location, Graphics e)
{
    Wheels(truckf.Size,location,e);  
}

private static void Wheels(Size simage,Point location,Graphics e)
{
    e.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, location.X / 6F, location.Y / 1.43F, 20, 20);
}
```

Comment: You are creating a new PictureBox every time your form paints. Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: It dosent really matters now, its an early version of the app, I just need to know now how to draw on top of an image, I can also cahnge the control if it needed

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to handle the Load event on your form. Also the `PictureBox` is a control and you need to draw an image and hand it to the PictureBox to get this to work. Try this:

```
    private PictureBox pb;

    private void Truck_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pb = new PictureBox();
        pb.Location = new Point(10, 25);
        Image bg = Image.FromFile("fire2_clipped_rev_1.png");
        pb.BackgroundImage = bg;
        pb.Size = bg.Size;
        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(pb.Size.Width, pb.Size.Height);
        pb.Image = img;
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
        {
            Truck.TruckF(pb.Location, g);
        }
        Controls.Add(pb);
    }
```